# MongoDB: Should You Pre-Allocate a Document if Using $addToSet or $push?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I've been studying up on MongoDB and I understand that it is highly recommended that documents structures are completely built-out (pre-allocated) at the point of insert, this way future changes to that document do not require the document to be moved around on the disk. Does this apply when using $addToSet or $push?

For example, say I have the following document:

```
"_id" : "rsMH4GxtduZZfxQrC",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2015-03-01T12:08:23.007Z"),
"market" : "LTC_CNY",
"type" : "recentTrades",
"data" : [ 
    {
        "date" : "1422168530",
        "price" : 13.8,
        "amount" : 0.203,
        "tid" : "2435402",
        "type" : "buy"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "1422168529",
        "price" : 13.8,
        "amount" : 0.594,
        "tid" : "2435401",
        "type" : "buy"
    }, 
    {
        "date" : "1422168529",
        "price" : 13.79,
        "amount" : 0.594,
        "tid" : "2435400",
        "type" : "buy"
    }
]
```

And I am using one of the following commands to add a new array of objects (`newData`) to the `data` field:

$addToSet to add to the end of the array:

```
Collection.update(
  { _id: 'rsMH4GxtduZZfxQrC' },
  {
    $addToSet: {
      data: {
        $each: newData
      }
    }
  }
);
```

$push (with $position) to add to the front of the array:

```
Collection.update(
  { _id: 'rsMH4GxtduZZfxQrC' },
  {
    $push: {
      data: {
        $each: newData,
        $position: 0
      }
    }
  }
);
```

The `data` array in the document will grow due to new objects that were added from `newData`. So will this type of document update cause the document to be moved around on the disk?

For this particular system, the `data` array in these documents can grow to upwards of 75k objects within, so if these documents are indeed being moved around on disk after every $addToSet or $push update, should the document be defined with 75k nulls (`data: [null,null...null]`) on insert, and then perhaps use $set to replace the values over time? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that it is highly recommended that documents structures are completely built-out (pre-allocated) at the point of insert, this way future changes to that document do not require the document to be moved around on the disk. Does this apply when using $addToSet or $push?

It's recommended if it's feasible for the use case, which it usually isn't. Time series data is a notable exception. It doesn't really apply with `$addToSet` and `$push` because they tend to increase the size of the document by growing an array.

> the data array in these documents can grow to upwards of 75k objects within

Stop. Are you sure you want constantly growing arrays with tens of thousands of entries? Are you going to query wanting specific entries back? Are you going to index any fields in the array entries? You probably want to rethink your document structure. Maybe you want each `data` entry to be a separate document with fields like `market`, `type`, `createdAt` replicated in each? You wouldn't be worrying about document moves.

Why will the array grow to 75K entries? Can you do less entries per document? Is this [time series data](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb)? It's great to be able to preallocate documents and do in-place updates with the mmap storage engine, but it's not feasible for every use case and it's not a requirement for MongoDB to perform well.

> should the document be defined with 75k nulls (data: [null,null...null]) on insert, and then perhaps use $set to replace the values over time?

No, this is not really helpful. The document size will be computed based on the BSON size of the null values in the array, so when you replace `null` with another type the size will increase and you'll get document rewrites anyway. You would need to preallocate the array with objects with all fields set to a default value for its type, e.g.

```
{
    "date" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")    // use a date type instead of a string date
    "price" : 0,
    "amount" : 0,
    "tid" : "000000", // assuming 7 character code - strings icky for default preallocation
    "type" : "none"    // assuming it's "buy" or "sell", want a default as long as longest real values
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this was very helpful! Yes, this is time-series data. I am generating several course resolutions based on new objects that come in (roughly 1 object/second), and those documents are the ones being used in the client subscription. But I'm trying to figure out the best way to store the raw objects, which I pretty much only want to keep around incase I need them as reference in the future, i.e. needing to regenerate my course resolutions due to system failure, etc. What's the best way to store hundreds of thousands of these sized raw objects that the client doesn't need?

Comment: Currently, I have the document structure described in the original post above. There is a `data` field, which is an array that grows in length. Once that Array grows to 75k objects in size, I insert a new document with the same structure and start addingToSet there. So I'm accruing a bunch of documents that are 75k objects in length. 75k was chosen because due to this particular object size, 75k of them equate to ~7.5MB in document size, and I didn't want to come near the 16MB hard limit to avoid console warnings. Perhaps you can also let me know if that approach is correct or not?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB uses the power of two allocation strategy to store your documents, which means it will allocate the size of the document^2 for storage. Therefore if your nested arrays don't lead to a total growth larger then the original size to the power of two, mongo will not have to reallocate the document.

See: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage/

Comment: Power of 2 allocation does not necessarily obviate the problem where arrays grow beyond these lengths. The best case is to assess your usage patterns and design/pre-allocate based on the actual requirements for storage as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line here is that any "document growth" is pretty much always going to result in the "physical move" of the storage allocation unless you have "pre-allocated" by some means on the original document submission. Yes there is "power of two" allocation, but this does not always mean anything valid to your storage case.

The additional "catch" here is on ["capped collections"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), where indeed the "hidden catch" is that such "pre-allocation" methods are likely not to be "replicated" to other members in a replica set if those instructions fall outside of the "oplog" period where the replica set entries are applied.

Growing any structure beyond what is allocated from an "initial allocation" or the general tricks that can be applied **will** result in that document being "moved" in storage space when it grows beyond the space it was originally supplied with.

In order to ensure this does not happen, then you always "pre-allocate" to the expected provisions of your data on the original creation. And with the obvious caveat of the condition already described.

Comment: Would you recommend defining the document with 75k nulls (`data: [null,null...null]`) on insert, and then perhaps using $set to replace the null values over time with the actual objects? Rather than using $addToSet to dynamically grow the document over time? Does that solve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: @JonCursi Of course when you submit multiple values with the same "set"  result these will be "nullified" by the server itself as a process of `$addToSet` since they are the same. It's not recommended though and you probably should sort that out in client code before submitting.