# MongoDB, what is the most efficient means of storing strings of N size

Tags: string, mongodb, database-performance

I'm modelling an application where many different documents can have many "TextBlock" documents. TextBlock documents will be responsible for storing strings that range from 1 to 10000 char of natural language provided by the user.

For the sake of argument, let us assume that:

- 25% of TextBlocks will store 2500 or less char,
- 25% will store >2500 to <=5000 char,
- 25% will store >5000 to <=7500 char,
- 25% will store >7500 to <=10000 char.

The context is a small commercial enterprise with a footfall of roughly two hundred users a day; there is no reason why that number wouldn't grow with time however.

How does mongo perform with storing large String fields? Does it make sense to break the TextBlock model into respective "Small", "Medium", "Long", "extraLong" fields and only set a field as and when it's needed? Or maintain a single "text" field? Or maintain 4 separate Models (Small, Medium, Long, ExtraLong)?

Comment: I was looking for this document, 

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/mmapv1/#power-of-2-allocation

My guess would be that power of 2 document allocation is decided per document.  In theory, if I only need to perform unset when a TextBlock's data changes size, then having  "small", "medium", "long", "extraLong" fields probably aren't a bad idea.

The following is also of interest,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808858/mongodb-should-you-pre-allocate-a-document-if-using-addtoset-or-push

Comment: The article you are mentioned describes memory allocation by old storage engine (MongoDB 3.2+ it uses another engine by default) - just to be sure you are notice this fact. Also I believe that split same data into 4 different models it is not a good idea - this will add extra headache to maintain it. 10 000 chars * 2 byte per char (utf8) = 20 kb. I don't consider this as big document for mongodb. I don't know sure, but I think you can faced only with indexing (building storing and using index) such long string field (if you need index it of course). Need to investigate this issue.

Comment: It's as much an issue about quantity. The backbone of the development is - in some respects - similar to a desktop publishing suite.  Assume that each user is writing hundreds of TextBlocks